# Como colocar um footer como rodapé de página sem usar css ou javascript?

Tags: html5

Estou aprendendo HTML5 e estou com esta duvida, é possível deixar a tag footer no rodapé das paginas sem usar CSS ou javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não**, não da forma certa...

As tags tem apenas um sentido semântico, ou seja elas não estão pre-estilizadas para funcionarem de acordo com seu objetivo, essas novas tags vieram para dar uma harmonia na construção das paginas, isso foi criado pela falta de recursos do html  na época, tudo se resumia a tabelas e divs, isso era muito ruim para os mecanismos de busca ou a navegação pelo conteúdo da pagina. então as novas tags vieram para dar suporte a nova forma de construir sites/conteúdo na web, claro que não é somente restrito a isso, veja a imagem a seguir, ilustra bem a semântica proposta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Veja aqui uma referencia sobre a semântica no html5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

Existe um style default em cada tag, mas normalmente é evitado na construção de layouts, os design costumam usar [Reset Stylesheet](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) para tirar os valores padrões de estilo.